# Requesting a MMA tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

i am a huge mma fan and didn't find a tag to the worlds fastest growing sport. Can we please create one ? 
Of course it would be a pleasure for me to be listed as the creator :)
Thanks

Comment: Ask a question about MMA, and I will add the tag for you.

Comment: done it, thank you.

Comment: tag created....

Comment: This question's status is `completed`.